# Bullet raycast from bottom of btRigidBody

Tags: c++, ogre, bulletphysics

This probably is a simple question, I made a working ray casting from the center of my `btRigidBody` object, but it always hits itself (as it is casted from the center).

What would be the best approach to use a ray cast from the bottom part of my body down the Y-axis? As I want to know if my body is touching the floor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just set the ray origin to the position right underneath your rigid body?